# ? 1.0 : 0.0 - What does this mean?

Tags: javascript, glsl, shader

Maybe a stupid question for you, but I found a site where this source was given with no further info. I searched with google but I got no useful suggestions.

I want to know what this line actually does. Give me a link or the name of this function? so I can look it up myself.

Thank you :)

```
y += (x<= uz ? 1.0 : 0.0) * radius;
```

I know what += and * do, but the rest is a huge questionmark

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/be21c7hw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx).

> **Conditional (Ternary) Operator (?:)**
>
> Returns one of two expressions depending on a condition.
>
> ```
> test ? expressionIfTrue : expressionIfFalse
> ```

With your code it is the same as:

```
if (x<uz) {
  y += radius;
} else {
  y += 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That is a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). Basically this translates to:

```
var y;
// ...

if( x <= uz ) {
  y += 1.0 * radius;
} else {
  y += 0.0 * radius;
}
```